# Accessing One level up of Parent in SASS

Tags: sass

I have a code like

```
.portlet {  
    .portlet-body {
        .microsites {
            .portlet-body {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I remove repetition of `.portlet-body` using SASS? I read about `&` but that isn't helping me. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 3):

This could be a solution:

```
.portlet-body {
  .portlet & {
  }
  .microsites & {
  }
}
```